# SQL Server How do you get the sum of a column with condition that if its less than 0, add from another column else add that column?

Tags: sql-server

```
select 
  sum(case when Apt.productionValue != '-1.0' then Apt.subTotal 
    else Apt.productionValue end) as ProductionValue,Apt.date
from Appointment Apt
group by Apt.date 
order by Apt.date asc
```

| ApppointmentID | Production Value | SubTotal | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | 10 | 2021-09-02 |
| 2 | 10 | 0 | 2021-09-02 |
| 3 | -1 | 20 | 2021-09-01 |
| 4 | -1 | 20 | 2021-09-01 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 2021-09-01 |

I'm trying to get the sum of Production value only if it is over 0, else add subtotal instead for that row.

End goal is to still have 20 as the sum for 2021-09-02 and 45 for 2021-09-01

Comment: So what are your expected results here?

Comment: `have 10 as the sum for 2021-09-02`, sure? Not 20?

Comment: @vernou Yea youre right its 20. Expected results would be 20 for 2021-09-02 and 45 for 2021-09-01

Comment: From your explanation I would change your not equals condition to " < 0". But since your code is using a string for comparison I question what your datatype is. Are you storing these as strings? The other issue is that your desired output values do not seem to match your description.

Comment: @SeanLange It is an decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close in your attempt. This should work based on the sample data provided.

```
select Apt.[Date]
    , sum(case when Apt.ProductionValue < 0 then Apt.SubTotal else Apt.ProductionValue end)
from Appointment  Apt
group by Apt.[Date]
order by Apt.[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the expected column in a subquery like :

```sql
select Date, SUM(ProductionValue) as ProductionValue
from (
    select
        Date,
        case when ProductionValue > 0
            then ProductionValue 
            else SubTotal end
        as ProductionValue
    from Appointment
) as d
group by Date
order by Date
```